# combine html template files into one JS file

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, gulp, underscore.js-templating

1. I have HTML template files (underscore template syntax)
2. These files are saved in HTML format so they would be easy to edit (IDE syntax highlight)
3. I don't want to fetch them with ajax, but rather combine them all and include them as a`js` file.
4. Using GULP as my task-runner, I would like it to somehow [combine all](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-html2txt) the HTML to something like this, as a javascript file that I could include in my BUILD process:

*`template_file_name` is the HTML file name.*

```
var templates = {
   template_file_name : '...template HTML string...',
   template_file_name2 : '...template HTML string...',
   template_file_name3 : '...template HTML string...'
}
```

I don't really know how to approach this, and how to create such text from all the files..yes I can convert each individual file to a string, but how can I put it inside an object?

---

## Update - Oct 25, 15 - ES6 modules:

For those who want your templates as ES6 modules, I have created [gulp-file-contents-to-modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-file-contents-to-modules)

#### Demo output:

```
export var file_name = "This is bar.";
export var file_name2 = "This is foo.\r\n";
export var my-folder__file_name = "This is baz.\r\n";
```

---

### All my NPM packages related to combining template files using gulp:

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-file-contents-to-keys
2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-file-contents-to-modules
3. https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-template-compile-es6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found this wonderful tool which does exactly what I want:

**https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-template-compile**

### Usage *(as simple as)*:

```
gulp.task('templates', function () {
    gulp.src('./views/templates/**/*.html')
        .pipe(template()) // converts html to JS
        .pipe(concat('templates.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./js/dist/'))
});
```

Then you can access the key/value object with `window.JST`. The values are functions (I don't know why, but it's like that)

### Update - August 21, 2015

I've decided to use use [gulp-file-contents-to-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-file-contents-to-json) which is the most simple thing possible for generating JSON from files' contents.

### Update - July 19, 2016

I've created 3 NPM packages (might be handy to someone):

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-file-contents-to-keys
2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-file-contents-to-modules
3. https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-template-compile-es6

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-html-to-json.

It has a various feature and very easy to use. It will generate exactly what output you need.

```
var templates = {
   template_file_name : '...template HTML string...',
   template_file_name2 : '...template HTML string...',
   template_file_name3 : '...template HTML string...'
}
```

It also has angular`templateCache` generator if you use `angularjs`.

Comment: Thanks I will check it out. (I hate angularJs btw)

Comment: For now it doesn't work (the output is empty) I have notified the repository owner.

Answer (score 0):

Another tool I just discovered for all handlebars.js users out there is `gulp-handlebars`.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-handlebars

https://github.com/lazd/gulp-handlebars

After adapting the sample gulp task to my needs I was able to include the `template.js` in my `index.html` and access every single template with a Handlebars wrapper via `Template.[filename]()`.

e.g. `Template.cart(data);` returns the HTML string with all data filled in.

Comment: I don't think such a tool should care about which files it is fed of. you give it files, and it creates a javascript file with variables (file name) equals content of that file (in string). that's it.

Comment: I agree. Yet - it exists and I tried it so it's a possible solution. Will try the one you suggested too.

Comment: @vsync apparently the tool you linked also does care about what files its fed.