# Basic JavaScript template for JSON data to HTML with template string being a JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, templates

I am looking for a simple function or library that is very small and lightweight that will simply allow me to define a template which has placeholders that are  populated from a JSON data result like the one below.

Most JavaScript template libraries I saw require you to define the template HTML inside of the page HTML either in a hidden DIV or inside `<script>` tags...

```
<script id="template" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
<div>
    <ul>
      <li>{{first_name}} {{last_name}} goes by the username of: {{user_name}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</script>
```

---

**I need to be able to define the template HTML as a JavaScript string instead of like the above method...**

---

```
var templateString = '<div>'+
'<ul>'+
'  <li>{{first_name}} {{last_name}} goes by the username of: {{user_name}}</li>'+
'</ul>'+
'</div>';
```

And then pass it some JSON like below and have it parse it to an HTML string which I can then manually inject into my DOM.

Can this be done without a fancy library?  If I need a library, any suggestion for one that will work in the manner described above?  As mentioned most that I saw require the template to be defined outside of JavaScript.

**JSON DATA**

```
{  
    "1":{  
        "id":"1",
        "user_name":"jasondavis",
        "first_name":"Jason",
        "last_name":"Davis",
        "is_admin":"1",
        "gravatar_id":"http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/31b64e4876d603ce78e04102c67d6144?s=80&d=identicon&r=PG",
        "gravatar_url":"http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/31b64e4876d603ce78e04102c67d6144?s=80&d=identicon&r=PG"
    },
    "1702c3d0-df12-2d1b-d964-521becb5e3ad":{  
        "id":"1702c3d0-df12-2d1b-d964-521becb5e3ad",
        "user_name":"Jeff",
        "first_name":"Jeff",
        "last_name":"Mosley",
        "is_admin":"1",
        "gravatar_id":"http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/5359bf585d11c5c35602f9bf5e66fa5e?s=80&d=identicon&r=PG",
        "gravatar_url":"http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/5359bf585d11c5c35602f9bf5e66fa5e?s=80&d=identicon&r=PG"
    },
    "1d77045b-fb16-d925-b19e-52c85d82bf81":{  
        "id":"1d77045b-fb16-d925-b19e-52c85d82bf81",
        "user_name":"PortalUser",
        "first_name":"Portal",
        "last_name":"User",
        "is_admin":"0",
        "gravatar_id":"http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/0be68519dd27dc4586ad2246e7c1c2d6?s=80&d=identicon&r=PG",
        "gravatar_url":"http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/0be68519dd27dc4586ad2246e7c1c2d6?s=80&d=identicon&r=PG"
    },
    "4bc81f9c-992f-ed11-5c64-558f5de81a87":{  
        "id":"4bc81f9c-992f-ed11-5c64-558f5de81a87",
        "user_name":"testtest",
        "first_name":"test",
        "last_name":"test",
        "is_admin":"0",
        "gravatar_id":"http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/309bdb7b06aeb214c4fe6963e64de168?s=80&d=identicon&r=PG",
        "gravatar_url":"http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/309bdb7b06aeb214c4fe6963e64de168?s=80&d=identicon&r=PG"
    },
    "6ce98c71-80c8-8b04-1767-52ccdd1b7c96":{  
        "id":"6ce98c71-80c8-8b04-1767-52ccdd1b7c96",
        "user_name":"TestUser",
        "first_name":"John",
        "last_name":"Doe",
        "is_admin":"0",
        "gravatar_id":"http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/309bdb7b06aeb214c4fe6963e64de168?s=80&d=identicon&r=PG",
        "gravatar_url":"http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/309bdb7b06aeb214c4fe6963e64de168?s=80&d=identicon&r=PG"
    },
    "95803cf3-84ea-493a-a030-52b0abcd9b0c":{  
        "id":"95803cf3-84ea-493a-a030-52b0abcd9b0c",
        "user_name":"test",
        "first_name":"test",
        "last_name":"test",
        "is_admin":"0",
        "gravatar_id":"http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/309bdb7b06aeb214c4fe6963e64de168?s=80&d=identicon&r=PG",
        "gravatar_url":"http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/309bdb7b06aeb214c4fe6963e64de168?s=80&d=identicon&r=PG"
    },
    "seed_chris_id":{  
        "id":"seed_chris_id",
        "user_name":"chris",
        "first_name":"Chris",
        "last_name":"Olliver",
        "is_admin":"0",
        "gravatar_id":"http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/9655f78d38f380d17931f8dd9a227b9f?s=80&d=identicon&r=PG",
        "gravatar_url":"http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/9655f78d38f380d17931f8dd9a227b9f?s=80&d=identicon&r=PG"
    },
    "seed_jim_id":{  
        "id":"seed_jim_id",
        "user_name":"jim",
        "first_name":"Jim",
        "last_name":"Brennan",
        "is_admin":"0",
        "gravatar_id":"http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/db40f846ab0a3b10522f83c6ae657e31?s=80&d=identicon&r=PG",
        "gravatar_url":"http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/db40f846ab0a3b10522f83c6ae657e31?s=80&d=identicon&r=PG"
    },
    "seed_max_id":{  
        "id":"seed_max_id",
        "user_name":"max",
        "first_name":"Max",
        "last_name":"Jensen",
        "is_admin":"0",
        "gravatar_id":"http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/e4f7cd8905e896b04425b1d08411e9fb?s=80&d=identicon&r=PG",
        "gravatar_url":"http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/e4f7cd8905e896b04425b1d08411e9fb?s=80&d=identicon&r=PG"
    },
    "seed_sally_id":{  
        "id":"seed_sally_id",
        "user_name":"sally",
        "first_name":"Sally",
        "last_name":"Bronsen",
        "is_admin":"0",
        "gravatar_id":"http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/62bc326ac7fca09505ad10b8b1e0d9c5?s=80&d=identicon&r=PG",
        "gravatar_url":"http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/62bc326ac7fca09505ad10b8b1e0d9c5?s=80&d=identicon&r=PG"
    },
    "seed_sarah_id":{  
        "id":"seed_sarah_id",
        "user_name":"sarah",
        "first_name":"Sarah",
        "last_name":"Smith",
        "is_admin":"0",
        "gravatar_id":"http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/62a9731a313984d2576cd2b5528c0725?s=80&d=identicon&r=PG",
        "gravatar_url":"http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/62a9731a313984d2576cd2b5528c0725?s=80&d=identicon&r=PG"
    },
    "seed_will_id":{  
        "id":"seed_will_id",
        "user_name":"will",
        "first_name":"Will",
        "last_name":"Westin",
        "is_admin":"0",
        "gravatar_id":"http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/6976b4087070908d7c4c12ef3fc21d8b?s=80&d=identicon&r=PG",
        "gravatar_url":"http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/6976b4087070908d7c4c12ef3fc21d8b?s=80&d=identicon&r=PG"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### html => JS

[combine html template files into one JS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22934469/combine-html-templates-files-into-one-js-file)

#### template using templateString

```
var templateString = "<div><ul><li>{{first_name}} {{last_name}} goes by the username of: {user_name}}</li> </ul></div>";
var compiled = _.template(templateString);
compiled({ 'first_name': 'foo', last_name: "bar", user_name: "foobar" });
// → '"<div><ul><li>foo bar goes by the username of: foobar</li> </ul></div>"'
```

### underscore/lodash (if you are already these libraries)

https://lodash.com/docs#template

```
// using custom template delimiters
_.templateSettings.interpolate = /{{([\s\S]+?)}}/g; // changing to use {{}}
var compiled = _.template('hello {{ user }}!');
compiled({ 'user': 'mustache' });
// → 'hello mustache!'
```

### mustache

https://github.com/janl/mustache.js

#### JS

```
function loadUser() {
  var template = $('#template').html();
  Mustache.parse(template);   // optional, speeds up future uses
  var rendered = Mustache.render(template, {name: "Luke"});
  $('#target').html(rendered);
}
```

#### HTML

```
<html>
<body onload="loadUser">
<div id="target">Loading...</div>
<script id="template" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
Hello {{ name }}!
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: THis is similar to my goal except the tempalate that is stored in the DOM script tags I am hoping to instead store inside a JS variable.  DO you know if that is possibble....pretend I dont have access to the page and only am loading my JS file to the page

Comment: are you storing your template in script tags or are you asking if it's possilble to store it in JS vars?

Comment: I am wanting to store my templates as a JS variable in my JS project.  So it would not be in script tags or in the DOM at all but instead contained within my JS FIle

Comment: Are you asking how to store it in JS or not to read templates from JS?

Comment: I want my template to be in a JS variable... `var templateString = '<div>{{placeholder}}</div>';`

Comment: this post explains few ways to convert html to js vars. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22934469/combine-html-templates-files-into-one-js-file

Comment: I think you may misunderstood.  I dont need to convert html to JS.  I just need a template library that allows me to use `var templateString = '<div>{{placeholder}}</div>';` as my template instead of requiring me to store the template inside page script tags

Comment: I updated my question to show better example and explanation

Comment: var template = $('#template').html(); **is the same as** var template = '<div>{{placeholder}}</div>'.

Comment: You just save yourslef the trouble of having to read the string from the DOM script tag.

Comment: `$('#template').html();` woudl require that my page DOM has an element with ID `template` that holds the HTML template....assume my page DOM does not have the tmeplkate in it at all!!!!!  THe template shoul;d not ever bve in the DOM it is only in the JS file as a JS variable sotored in a string

Comment: the templatre will not be in the DOM is my goal

Comment: The templating engines take the string template. Since those examples were storing the template in the DOM, those examples had to read the string template from DOM. But you already have your template in js, you can just use it like:    '''var compiled = _.template(templateString);
compiled({ 'user': 'mustache' });'''

Comment: So you are saying this would work... `var compiled = _.template(<div><ul><li>{{first_name}} {{last_name}} goes by the username of: {user_name}}</li> </ul></div>);`

Comment: Yes, see my updated example. Just make sure the template is in quotes (because it needs to be a string)

Comment: I see now, that is all I wanted, sorry it got confusing somewhere.  `var compiled = _.template(<div><ul><li>{{first_name}} {{last_name}} goes by the username of: {user_name}}</li> </ul></div>);` is all I need to do

Comment: var compiled = _.template("<div><ul><li>{{first_name}} {{last_name}} goes by the username of: {user_name}}</li> </ul></div>"); Don't forget the quotes.

Comment: thanks will select your answer soon.  I have a JSFiddle example here http://jsfiddle.net/utgrLw96/22/ with demo of template in JS var and in DOM script tags however it does not work with my JSON data.  Any ideas to fix?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/utgrLw96/23/ you were missing the mustache library and your user info is nested inside of "jsonData.seed_will_id"

Comment: My issue is each user is nested under a different key so for example `jsonData.seed_will_id` is only 1 users data in the JSON list of users.  I need to figure out how to parse each user. `seed_sarah_id"`, `seed_sally_id`, etc...It looks like I might have to modify the JSON data which seems like a pain

Comment: going to start a new question for this thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Updating for ES6+ without any frameworks you'd do something like this:

```
const userHtml = (user) => { return `
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>${user.first_name} ${user.last_name} goes by the username of: ${user.user_name}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>`;
}

const writeUsers = (articles) => {
    //where the html in the template goes
    const userListContainer = document.getElementById("userlist");

    users.forEach(user => {
        userListContainer.innerHTML += userHtml(user);
    });

}

fetch(datasrc)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => writeUsers(json));
```

You might have to adjust this a little based on your JSON format.  You might also check out the `<template>` element if you are interested in a more HTML-centric approach.

Comment: Note: I didn't mention any "modern" framework solution since really unless you have a massive site that needs an enterprise framework like Angular, React, UI5, etc then you probably don't need to use one at all.  They are almost entirely obsolete now, and as such contribute to unnecessary bloat.