# How can I use a template that is located in a separate file with mustache JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mustache

Okay so I want to separate my html and javascript for my project. I want to define a template in a file called template.htm and then use javascript/jQuery to get the file and add the JSON data etc to it then to render/compile it.

Script:

```
(function(){
    //this is our JSON (data)

    var data = {
        "cities": [
            {"name": "London"},
            {"name": "Paris"},
            {"name": "Munich"}
        ]
    },

    //get a reference to our HTML template
    src = $.get('../template.html');
    template = src.filter("#test").html()

    //tell Mustache.js to iterate through the JSON and insert the data into the HTML template
    output = Mustache.render(template, data);

    //append the HTML template to the DOM
    $('#container').append(output);
})();
```

Comment: Do you use GULP maybe? I wouldn't recommend fetching each HTML template file via ajax, but rather bundle them or import each one you need prior to the building of your application code, to avoid slow ajax calls

Comment: see this question - http://stackoverflow.com/q/22934469/104380

Answer (score 5):

Here's a 2018 version using fetch to retrieve both the data and the template in parallel:

```
// Get external data with fetch
const data = fetch('data.json').then(response => response.json());

// Get external template with fetch
const template = fetch('template.mst').then(response => response.text());

// wait for all the data to be received
Promise.all([data,template])
.then(response => {

    resolvedData = response[0];
    resolvedTemplate = response[1];

    // Cache the template for future uses
    Mustache.parse(resolvedTemplate);

    var output = Mustache.render(resolvedTemplate, resolvedData);

    // Write out the rendered template
     return document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = output;

}).catch(error => console.log('Unable to get all template data: ', error.message));
```

Answer (score 1):

From this article http://jonnyreeves.co.uk/2012/using-external-templates-with-mustachejs-and-jquery/

With JQuery you can `.get()` a file and then apply the Mustache rendering to it once it's arrived.

```
$.get('greetings.htm', function(templates) {
    // Fetch the <script /> block from the loaded external
    // template file which contains our greetings template.
    var template = $(templates).filter('#tpl-greeting').html();
    $('body').append(Mustache.render(template, templateData));
});
```

Additionally, if you want to use the Mustache JQuery plugin:

```
$.Mustache.load('greetings.htm', function() {
    $('body').mustache('tpl-greeting', templateData);
});
```

Comment: Any help @Soviut ?

Comment: This isn't a forum! If you have more issues, ask a new question. Be sure to mark this answer correct if it solved your problem (and revert your question since now now the answer doesn't make sense).